# Is there a collective name given to regions in the ocean which have been studied to affect climate?

Tags: climate, climatology

Would calling them hotspots be correct?

Comment: Are said regions known to have an effect on the climate, or have said regions been thourougly studied?

Comment: Yes, they have.

Comment: This was an "either-or"-question. You can't answer "yes" because it fits both options.

Comment: i vote to close this as unclear what you are asking,i have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: Are you saying certain regions of the ocean have a more significant impact on the climate?  I too am a little lost as to what you're trying to ask.